# Postgresql select date range between two tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables that have date fields in them. I want to select data from table 1 where the date is +/- 1 day from any date in table 2.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
select * from table1,table2 
where table1.date BETWEEN (table2.date - '1 day'::interval) 
AND (table2.date + '1 day'::interval) 
and ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If only +/- 1 day, you could use a workaround like this:

```
select col1, col2, ...
from table1 
where date_col in (select distinct date_col 
                      from table2
                      union all
                      select distinct (date_col - '1 day'::interval)
                      from table2
                      union all
                      select distinct (date_col + '1 day'::interval)
                      from table2
                     );
```

This has quite good peformance because the subquery only be calculated one time and will be cache for comparing